# Can I run a CodeIgniter database query without clearing it from the class?

Tags: codeigniter

I am using the CodeIgniter database class to generate results and then use the pagination class to navigation through them.  I have a model that retrieves member results from the table.  I would like to calculate the total number of rows from the query so I can pass this to the pagination class.  The count_all db helper function won't suffice because that doesn't take in account any "where" or "join" clauses that I include.

If this is my query:

```
$this->db->select('m.user_id AS id, m.email_address, m.display_name, m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date,
            l.listing_id, COUNT(l.member_id) AS total_listings,
            g.group_id AS group_id, g.title AS group_title')
    ->from('users AS m')
    ->join('listings AS l', 'm.user_id = l.member_id', 'left')
    ->join('groups AS g', 'm.group_id = g.group_id', 'left')
    ->group_by('m.user_id');
```

How can I continue to use this query if I wanted to do something like this:

```
if($query_total = $this->db->get()){

   $this->total_results = $query_total->num_rows();

}

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
if($query_members = $this->db->get()){

   return $query_members->result_array();
}
```

Update:  In other words, I want to run a query with the get() method without clearing it from the query builder when it's done running so I can use the top part of the query later.

Comment: what problem your are facing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it by using [Active Record Caching](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) (the last category on that page).

```
$this->db->start_cache(); // start caching
$this->db->select('m.user_id AS id, m.email_address, m.display_name, m.status, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.join_date) AS join_date,
        l.listing_id, COUNT(l.member_id) AS total_listings,
        g.group_id AS group_id, g.title AS group_title')
->from('users AS m')
->join('listings AS l', 'm.user_id = l.member_id', 'left')
->join('groups AS g', 'm.group_id = g.group_id', 'left')
->group_by('m.user_id');
$this->db->stop_cache(); // stop caching
```

Then you can use that query as much as you want.

```
if($query_total = $this->db->get()){

   $this->total_results = $query_total->num_rows();

}

$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
if($query_members = $this->db->get()){

   return $query_members->result_array();
}
```

You can also flush the cache when you don't want that cached query anymore.

```
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing any table name in $this->db->get() function.
Thank you

Comment: He already set `$this->db->from('users AS m');` so that no need to pass table name again in `get()` method.